# How do I (on Windows 10) set up a Godot project to be developed in C# and export to web/html5?

Tags: c#, mono, game-development, godot

I've got the project set up and it exports fine to Windows. However, under Project -> Export I can't click the "Export Project" button.

[image: Export settings page]

When I click on the "Manage Export Templates" button, I'm prompted to install 3.0.6.stable.mono, which I download and install from the default mirror.

[image: templage manager page]

Unfortunately, this does not enable the "Export Project" button. Additionally, I get an error when from the main editor I attempt to "Run in Browser." It says "Could not open template for export."

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This platform is not supported yet.

You can track the remaining platforms from the issues linked here:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/18364#issuecomment-406222102

Comment: Oh I see. Can you export from C++ to HTML 5?